# Eval loss when fine-tuning in an unsupervised way/pretraining?

Tags: transformer, fine-tuning, validation-loss

I'm fine-tuning the base Mixtral 8x7B model (4-bit quantized) with Lora on my own data, following these guidelines: https://www.stochastic.ai/blog/xfinance-vs-bloomberg-gpt

I'm first fine-tuning it in a self-supervised way, and then using the `SFTTrainer` on some conversational data as a final step. I'm not a deep learning engineer so I have no idea what I'm doing really, but I tried a few different hyperparameters at first to see which got the train loss down quickest.

I then chose the best out of them and trained for about 8 epochs over my text data (5MB of text data). train loss was still quite high (0.6), the eval loss kept increasing. However, I assume the eval loss at this stage with my setup is irrelevant for this NSP self-supervised stage of training.

Then finally, I used the `SFTTrainer` on conversational data for like 100 epochs (only 100 Q&A pairs, but high-quality and some with extensive answers of about 4k tokens). The train loss got extremely low but the eval loss kept rising. Weirdly I got pretty good results when testing the final model.

My first question is how do I know when to stop the first stage (self-supervised) of training, do I need to create some advanced validation loss function to see if the model is accurately learning patterns in the unstructured text data? Secondly, why would my eval loss in the second stage of training keep rising even though with each checkpoint, the performance seems to be getting better when I tried the model out after training?